# Twitter API - follower count for numerous users

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, tweepy

I'm super new to Python but I am trying to access the Twitter API to pull in the number of followers for a list of twitter handles (or user IDs - i have both datasets) and print them to a csv file. I've searched for quite some time for this but haven't found anything that has truly worked.

This is what I currently have:

```
import tweepy
import time
import csv
import sys


# Keys, tokens and secrets
consumer_key = 'REMOVED'
consumer_secret = 'REMOVED'
access_token = 'REMOVED'


 access_token_secret = 'REMOVED'

# Tweepy OAuthHandler
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

targets = [12345,123456] # All your targets here

for target in targets:
    user = api.get_user(target)
    print(user.name, user.followers_count)
```

My questions here are:

- Can I have all the targets in a pre populated file and have the follower count for each target print out in the column next to the IDs?
- How do I add in count-break since: The twitter API only allows 100 users to be searched for at a time...[so] what you'll need to do is iterate through each 100 users but staying within the rate limit.

Apologies if this is super basic and thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Answer to all your questions is yes it's possible, but I need some clarification. When I run your code I get two lines of output, each as `<user.name> <user.followers_count>`, (for example: `kevin mcsheehan 508`). What do you mean "print out in the column next to the IDs"? What column, what are the IDs?

Comment: As for reading from a file, create a file in the same location as your python script, say `targets.txt`, one ID on each line, then replace the line `for target in targets:` with these two lines: `with open('targets.txt', 'r') as targets:
    for target in targets.readlines():`

Comment: Thank you for this. Regarding your first question (and using the same example), I would like to have the results printed in a csv file that I could then export to Google Sheets or Excel. So ideally I would start with a csv file with - let's say - 100 usernames in column A. I would then run the script to print the follower count in column B next to the related username. So the output would be a csv file with "kevin_mcsheehan" in cell A1 and 508 in B1. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thank you. Okay this would write to a `csv` file splitting `username` and `followers_count` on columns `A` and `B`: `with open('targets.txt', 'r') as targets_file:
    with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outcsv:
        outfile = csv.writer(outcsv)
        for target in targets_file.readlines():
            user = api.get_user(target.strip())
            outfile.writerow([user.name.lower(), user.followers_count])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion in the comments:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals
import tweepy
import time
import unicodecsv as csv
import codecs
import sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

access_token = '' 
access_token_secret = ''
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

with open('targets.txt', 'r') as targets_file:
    targets_list = targets_file.readlines()

targets_list_filtered = filter(None, targets_list[0].split('\r'))

targets_list_cleaned = [] 

for item in targets_list_filtered:
    targets_list_cleaned.append(item.strip('\n'))

with codecs.open('output.csv', 'wb', 'utf-8') as outcsv:
    outfile = csv.DictWriter(outcsv, encoding='utf-8', fieldnames=['uID', 'Username', 'Follower Count', 'Verified'])
    outfile.writeheader()

    for idx, target in enumerate(targets_list_cleaned):
        try:
            user = api.get_user(target)
            outfile.writerow({'uID': target, 'Username': user.name, 'Follower Count': user.followers_count, 'Verified': user.verified})
            print idx, target, user.name, user.followers_count, user.verified
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            # outfile.writerow(e.message)
            print idx, target, e.message
```

example `targets.txt` file contents:

```
99795204
973058420
988290763
984965461
973058420
97074741
969892964
968396750
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145813/discussion-on-answer-by-downshift-twitter-api-follower-count-for-numerous-user).